# Is EF-SET English Certificate accepted?

Tags: gre, language-exams, toefl, ielts

Is [EF-SET English Certificate](https://www.efset.org/) accepted for higher education or jobs across the world? Did anyone try using that? I have not yet seen any place where they accept this.

Comment: In my experience, no.

Answer (score 7):

The EF-SET English certificate is a test you take online without any supervision. From [the EF-SET FAQ](https://www.efset.org/faq/):

> **If the test is available to the public online, how is it secured from cheating?**
>
> Because it is intended as a learning tool, using the EF SET to its fullest advantage is the learner’s own responsibility. [...]. As an adaptive English test that covers multiple CEFR levels from beginner to advanced, the EF SET is designed to be useful to an individual as a measure of growth in proficiency over time and as a proxy to other expensive, high-stakes English tests like TOEFL, TOEIC or IELTS. To take advantage of this design, we advise that the test taker follow the timing guidelines and not try to cheat the test.

The [homepage of EF-SET](https://www.efset.org/) has three "buttons":

> - Check your students
> - Evaluate your employees
> - Check your English

So the EF-SET test is intended either as a self-assessment tool, or as a tool that can be used by universities or companies to evaluate their students/employees, in which case **the company or university will take care of the supervision**.

If you come with an EF-SET certificate that you got by yourself, the institution has no way of knowing that it was really you who took the test. Therefore, it does not make much sense to accept this as proof of English knowledge. I have never seen this accepted at a university.

Answer (score 5):

I Was told to get the EFSET test from a company abroad and send the certificate to evaluate my English level. So I would say that it has some power. In fact, its a good test and very reliable if you are serious IMO.

Answer (score 3):

I use EF SET to enroll in Japanese University (Monbu Scholarship) and has been accepted by the University for further step. Now I still waiting the announcement for the scholarship in June.

Comment: FYI, I’ve been accepted by MEXT and got the scholarship last year (2021)...now I studying at Japan university and next year will be graduate in March. Good luck to everyone!